# How do I make my node express page uniqe to every new user

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

What I am using - EJS, JS, NODE, Express.

I am new to this and have been getting away with googling stuff so far.

So I am making a website and I want it to be unique for every new tab. Right now, if one person clicks a button that displays a message, and I go to a different tab and open the link, I can see the message that the first person set. I read something about express-session and session Id and sending the requests through the sessionID to make sure it is sent to the right person. But I don't know how to implement them here

EDIT: Here is my best attempt trying to make sense out of this.

```
router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
    Actors.find({}, (err, actorFound) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        } else {
                res.render("welcome", {
                    actors: actorFound,
                    findItems: suggested
                })
        }
    })
})
```

When I "call" this on local host it would basically dump everything from the data base. Which is what it is supposed to do. However, if I open localhost using a different web browser, (trying to simulate a different visitor) I would find that my data from actors is already dumped on the page. Does this make sense. I will try to explain anything specific if you have any question and thank you very much.

Comment: That sounds like you have a global variable you're modifying. You'll need to show some code.

Comment: edited it, added some code, Thanks.

Comment: ِYou can handle sessions using some ready libs like ```passport.js```